# Would it be a good idea to mutate half of the offspring of each GA generation 100% of the time and the other half 0% of the time?

Tags: genetic-algorithms, evolutionary-algorithms, genetic-operators

I was reading about genetic algorithms, and to my understanding a genetic algorithm (GA) is an algorithm that starts with an initial population of chromosomes, where each chromosome has associated with it a fitness score, and it evolves the population such that the chromosomes in the population have an on average better fitness score than the chromosomes in the initial population. A GA accomplishes this by selecting the chromosomes in the population with the best fitness scores, and then it combines those chromosomes using a crossover function to produce offspring chromosomes. Those offspring may or may not be mutated randomly according to a probability that the offspring will be mutated. This process of selection, crossover, and mutation is iterated (with each successive iteration of the population being called a 'generation') until the fitness score of the population as a whole is deamed satisfactory. Please correct me if any of this is wrong.

My idea is with regards to mutating the offspring produced during the crossover phase. In the relatively simple implementations of GAs that I've looked at on the internet, most seem to randomly mutate the offspring according to a mutation rate. For example, the offspring may have a ten percent chance of mutating. When the GA is ran, the fitness function generally improves a lot over the first several generations, but it often stagnates for a while when one chromosome takes over essentially the entire population and little mutation occurs. This problem can be partially solved by increasing the mutation rate, but that also increases the probability of having offspring with a lower fitness score than the parents if the mutation poorly affects the fitness score. My idea is to make it so that half of the offspring produced with each generation have a one hundred percent mutation rate, and the other half has a zero or relatively low mutation rate. This could potentially lower the number of generations necessary to reach a satisfactory fitness score.

Is this a good idea? Would it work? Would it be better than other methods of mutating the offspring of each crossover?